# What do I need to change in /etc/apache2/sites-avaible/default?

Tags: apache-2.2

As in when I check my website at domain.com to show the configuration of wordpress if it's unzipped cause right now when I check it it shows Index of / and my site is in /wordpress. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should do the trick

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory /var/www/wordpress>
 Options -Indexes IncludesNOEXEC FollowSymLinks
 Allow from all
 AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```